# how to mouse event entered and exited pane change color label java fxml controller

Tags: java, javafx

i want to change color my label "Kategori" when mouse pressed and exit on "paneKategori" (Look at the picture).
my code in fxml controller

```
    @FXML
void btnProdukMouseEntered(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
    if ( event.getSource() == paneKategori) {
        labelKategori.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000;");
    }

}
```

that is no working for me.

this my GUI in scene builder. 
[image: GUI]

Comment: Please explain what the problem is, post [mcve], and ask a question. The post does not include any question.

Answer (score 0):

Create handlers for the `MOUSE_PRESSED`, `MOUSE_DRAGGED` and `MOUSE_RELEASED` handlers. Check, if the event's location is inside the node in `MOUSE_DRAGGED`.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button button = new Button("Drag me");
    final String style = "-fx-background-color: red;";

    button.setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
        if (evt.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            button.setStyle(style);
        }
    });
    button.setOnMouseDragged(evt -> {
        if (evt.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            button.setStyle(button.contains(evt.getX(), evt.getY()) ? style : null);
        }
    });
    button.setOnMouseReleased(evt -> {
        button.setStyle(null);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

BTW: Checking the source in an event handler is bad practice in most cases, since you could easily avoid the check by only registering the event handler for the node you're comparing the `source` property of the event to.